# How To Show Tweets In Phone Gap

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, twitter, sencha-touch

currently i am working with phonegap in android.i want to disply twits of one company.i don't have any idea how to do it.if any one has worked on it than please show me some guide,
Thanks 
Aamirkhan I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a tutorial on phonegap site if you browse the wiki, with ajax calls to updates your tweets list :

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/42450600/PhoneGap%20Ajax%20Sample

HTH, Enjoy

Comment: @droid or Sephy hey can you tell me how did you fix it because i am checking this link and it is not showing anything about how to load tweets or how to integrate it in your app.